# Laravel API + React Frontend request with Axios returning 404 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I am trying to make a POST request from React to Laravel API. When I send a request in development mode request is successful but when I deployed API(:8000) and frontend (:80) on Apache2 request is blocked by strict-mode-policy and CORS error that says my request is missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin and 404 as a response. But Laravel and React pages are accessible in the browser. For making requests I use Axios.
And websites should have the same base URL `http://localhost`
I tried many solutions but none was working for me.

## Laravel 10.x cors

I've seen many users recommending making your middleware that adds headers to server responses. Something like this was added by default in Laravel (`conf/cors.php`);
My file looks like this

```
    'paths' => ['http://127.0.0.1:8000','http://localhost','api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    
    'exposed_headers' => ['*'],
    
    'max_age' => 0,
    
    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

And it's registered in `Kernel.php` like this

```
         protected $middlewareAliases = [
                 // 'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, <- this is custom middleware not in use now
                'cors' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
                'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
                ...
    
         protected $middleware = [
            // \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, <- This is custom 
    middleware not in use now
            \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
```

this is what I have in `api.php` when using CUSTOM middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'cors','prefix'=>'api'], function () 
{
    Route::post('/signup',[AuthController::class, 'signup']);
    Route::post('/login',[AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/logout',[AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/user/post',[PostController::class,'createPost']);
    Route::get('/user/post',[PostController::class,'getPostsInMonth']);
    
    Route::post('/media/upload',[UploadController::class,'upload']);

});
```

Even with custom middleware no success

```
    class Cors
    {
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
        {
            return $next($request)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With');
        }
    }
```

## Adding header in Apache Laravel VirtualHost file

```
    <VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerName website.com
        ServerAlias *.website.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot .../laravel/public
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
        <Directory ".../laravel">
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
            Order allow, deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

React Apache VirtualHost file looks very similar to the Laravel file

No success for me :(

## .htaccess in Laravel/public

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy 'cross-origin'
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
```

## Setting API address as a proxy

in `package.json` I added this line

```
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
```

also tried with the `http-proxy-middleware` package
and `setupProxy.js` in react/src folder

```
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    
    module.exports = function(app) {
     app.use(
        '/api/*',
        createProxyMiddleware({
          target: 'http://localhost:8000',
          changeOrigin: true,
        })
     );
    };
```

## axios client script

```
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const axiosClient = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api",
    })
    
    axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((config)=>{
        const token = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
        config.headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
        return config;
    })
    
    axiosClient.interceptors.response.use((response)=>{
        return response;
    },(error)=>{
        const {response} = error;
        if(response && response.status == 401){
            localStorage.removeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
        }
    
        throw error;
    })
    
    export default axiosClient;
```

I know I have many settings that make my websites insecure but this is just for development purposes.
Please help I've been struggling with this for three days ><

There are the results that I getting (sorry stack don't wanna me to upload images because of formatting)

```
![1]: https://pasteboard.co/feqZ6JrGrvBM.png
![2]: https://pasteboard.co/nluAk8scYXzY.png
![3]: https://pasteboard.co/JF7yiHhH4XtB.png
```

Comment: what is the whole error message ?

Comment: @xenooooo hi i added image url's to end of my question

Answer (score 0):

Ended up moving the whole project from /var/www folder and creating symbolic links only for the public folders of each site. Also in `<VirtualHost>` setting document root path same as `<Directory>` path. After that default CORS handler of laravel project started working as it has.